# Compare date time in Laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have start and end date time column in database

```
start_date             end_date             contact
2021-01-25 17:30:00    2021-01-25 20:30:00   xxxxxxxxx
2021-01-27 17:30:00    2021-01-28 19:30:00   xxxxxxxxx
```

Now i'm trying to get records which exists between these two date time, it should match mobile number also.I'm using below query but it is not filtering record

```
   $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($request->date));
   $contact_number=$request->contact_number;

$event=Event::where(function ($query)use($date,$contact_number){
    $query->where('start_date', '>=', $date)->where('end_date', '<=', $date);})->where('contact',$contact_number)->paginate(5);
```

Comment: Can you try `$query->where('start_date', '<=', $date)->where('end_date', '>=', $date);})` ?

Comment: If it's working, please do accept my answer, so it let know other that the issue is solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to invert the `>=` and `<=` signs

```php
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($request->date));
$contact_number = $request->contact_number;

$event = Event::where(function ($query) use ($date, $contact_number){
        $query->where('start_date', '<=', $date)
              ->where('end_date', '>=', $date);
    })
    ->where('contact',$contact_number)
    ->paginate(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Laravel 4+ offers you these methods: whereDay(), whereMonth(), whereYear()  and whereDate() .




Here are some ways to make the comparison :

->where('date', '<=', '2014-07-10 23:59:59')

->where('date', '<', '2014-07-11')

// '2014-07-11'
$dayAfter = (new DateTime('2014-07-10'))->modify('+1 day')->format('Y-m-d');

->where('date', '<', $dayAfter)
```

Comment: which laravel version are you using ?

Comment: I'm using laravel 7

Comment: Try this code 
$from = date('2018-01-01');

$to = date('2018-05-02');

Reservation::whereBetween('reservation_from', [$from, $to])->get();

Comment: I have only one date time in $date variable i want to compare it against two columns i.e. start_date and end_date in database, i want to compare time also

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$date = Carbon\Carbon::parse($request->date)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$contact_number=$request->contact_number;

$event=Event::where(function ($query)use($date,$contact_number){
    $query->where('start_date', '<=', $date)->where('end_date', '>=', $date);})->where('contact',$contact_number)->paginate(5);
```

Comment: @Azhar Alam : in my date variable i have this date `2021-02-12 16:03:00` in my db start_date and end_date column i have `2021-02-12 15:40:00`, `2021-02-12 19:40:00` these entries respectively, but it this query does not return any row

Comment: I have edited my answer . See it works or not